# Rails doesn't recognize boolean fields on legacy database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-migration

I've written a Rails application which uses a legacy MySQL database. One table contains this field

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `active` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
);
```

I've fixed the schema with

```
t.boolean "active",    :default => false
```

But rails doesn't recognize that field as boolean

```
[1] pry(main)> Article.new.active.class
=> Fixnum
```

This will create a problem on validations because I have this validator in my class

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_inclusion_of :active, :in => [true, false]
end
```

When I assign boolean values to that field they are converted to FixNum and the validation fails with message `"1 is not included in the list"`

If I generate a new app with the same model the generated sql code is

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
)
```

And everything works fine:

```
[1] pry(main)> Article.new.active.class
=> FalseClass
```

Is there any way to make my legacy column recognized as boolean (possibly without running a migration)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've [found out](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb#L45) that for MySQL boolean type is hardcoded to `tinyint(1)`

```
def simplified_type(field_type)
  return :boolean if adapter.emulate_booleans && field_type.downcase.index("tinyint(1)")

  case field_type
    when /enum/i, /set/i then :string
    when /year/i         then :integer
    when /bit/i          then :binary
  else
    super
  end
end
```

I've run this migration on my database to get that working

```
class ChangeBooleanFields < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :articles, :active, :boolean, :null => false, :default => false, :limit => nil
  end

  def down
    change_column :articles, :active, :integer, :null => false, :default => 0, :limit => 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

short of [overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192978/why-does-ruby-have-trueclass-and-falseclass-instead-of-a-single-boolean-class/3194797#3194797) methods in the `TrueClass` and `FalseClass`, would it be acceptable to simply define your own "legacy" boolean values for use in your validations, along these lines:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  $legacy_false, $legacy_true = 0, 1
  validates_inclusion_of :active, :in => [$legacy_true, $legacy_false]
end
```

Comment: I'd also allow `true` & `false`, unless they're not working at all (i.e. trying to insert `true` or `false` in that column gives incorrect result) with the legacy storage.